# Why sign changed when I had put derivative respect to time before another value?

Tags: calculus

In [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2963530/970649), he wrote that

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{d}{dt}\delta q=-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta q$$

My question is why the sign changed when he had put derivative respect to time before Lagrangian "formalism". Even someone in [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266457/derive-euler-lagrange#comment8875549_4266457) told me the same thing. But I couldn't understand. I think I am missing something in Differentiation,ain't I?

Answer (score 1):

He is partially integrating $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta \dot{q} dt$ and assume that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta q$ is $0$ on the bounds.

Comment: It wasn't my question. My question was about sign not this one..

Comment: When you partiallyintegrate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta \dot{q} dt = \left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial q } \delta q\right]_0^1 - \int_{0}^{1} \delta q\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} dt $

Comment: The minus sign comes from the partial integration.